# Kubuntu: Broken Plasma Desktop after accidentally removing packages

Tags: kubuntu, kde, radeon, plasma

While trying to install unofficial radeon drivers from [padoka](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa), I've ended up with broken package (some intel-related file has been modified by both ubuntu ppa and padoka one). Apt suggested running apt-get with `--fix-broken` parameter, so I did. As a result of this, half of my DE had been uninstalled - file manager, utilities, etc.

I've reinstalled `kubuntu-full` package and got most of it back, but something must be still missing, as my desktop (after reboot) looks like this:

[image: Icons on desktop (not in dolphin) and most of the themeable resources are missing]

**I've tried:**

- logging in as another user - same situation.
- switching DE to xfce - xfce is unnafected and works OK.
- reinstalling all packages - no difference.
- observing auto-removable packages - list contains 100 entries, these may be dependencies of some packages I've failed to reinstall after the "fix broken". Possibly notable examples: gir1.2-*, kde-wallpapers-default, libvulkan1, libwayland-bin, many python libraries.

**So, my actual questions:**

- which packages are responsible for rendering the missing elements?
- which log files could contain info regarding this?

Thanks for any help; I would love to keep my current installation and avoid full system reinstall...

Edit, Additional info:

- Kubuntu 17.04
- Kde Plasma 5.94
- Kernel 4.10.0-19-g

Everything else - graphics related or not - seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the previous comment.

After some tests I managed to recover my KDE desktop by installing all the libqt5* packages.

```
apt-cache search libqt5 | awk '{print $1}'| grep -v "\-dev" | grep -v "\-dbg"
```

I was not able to detect the exact missing packages so this solution is a little a "brute force" one.

After the install you need to logoff / logon and the KDE desktop should be  right in place.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, kind person on the internet :)
I had to do minor tweak to get it working: I had to remove -gles packages from the list; also, somehow kwin-x11 package was missing too. But after installing all this, my KDE is back in all its glory!